# ValueError: The 'field_name' attribute has no file associated with it - only when updating?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-django-storages

I use DRF and django-storages to upload files to a S3 bucket.

I can create from the admin or from a POST to the API endpoint any new entry with a file.

But for some reason, as soon as I try to update the instance (be it from the admin or from the API endpoint), I get a `ValueError` that seems to indicate that **DRF can't find the file.**

But when I use Django's admin or shell, I see that the file has been correctly saved (`FieldFile` on instance) and that the file has been saved in the bucket.

**I don't override anything**: not the admin forms, not the serializer's update method, not the view's retrieve method, etc.

I have no idea how that could even be possible.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution. Somewhere in my code one of the serializer's fields had a `to_representation()` method that was returning the `instance` instead of the `instance.url`. I hope that this will help anyone.